# Euclid's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

In the examples of Euclid's algorithm to calculate `gcd(x, y)`, `x` is always larger then `y`. Does this condition matter? What happens if `x` is smaller then `y`? Why does this program still returns correct result even if the entered values for `x` is smaller then `y`?

```
import acm.program.*;
/*
GCD Algorithm - greatest common divisor. "Euclid Algorithm approach"

 */
public class EuclidsAlgorithm extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run(){
        println("This program is calculating the gratest common divisor (GCD) of two numbers.");
        int x = readInt("Enter 1st number: ");
        int y = readInt("Enter 2nd number: ");
        println("GCD(" + x + ", " + y + ") = " + gcd(x, y) );
    }

    private int gcd(int m, int k){
        int r = m % k;
        while (r != 0){
            m = k;
            k = r;
            r = m % k;
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about trying it with both `x > y` and `x < y` inputs, and debugging.

Comment: side note: add `static` to declaration: `private static int gcd(...)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko maybe he should also add generics to the method, in case he wanted to deal with longs?.. Why add things where they are unnecessary?

Comment: There is a variable shift in every loop: m <-- k <-- r=m' exchanging the roles of the variables (taking the division rest).

Comment: @Coderino Javarino: IMHO it depends. If you don't plan to work with `long` etc. you may want not to migrate from *primitive* types to generics (imagine that you have to apply `gcd` to, say, an array with million int pairs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the inputs doesn't matter to the result.

If `m < k`, then the initial value of `r` is simply `m`; then `m` receives the value of `k`, and `k` receives the value of `r`, which is `m`.

As such, the inputs are effectively swapped around on the first iteration of the loop, so that `m > k`.

Obviously doing this first iteration to swap the inputs takes (slightly) longer than not: if you are able to call the method in such a way that the inputs are already in the `m > k` order, then you save some work.

Comment: It doesn't matter to the output, but it matters for "softer" reasons.  Examples always put the larger one first, because nobody wants to show the first step just swapping the inputs.  Real implementations will often swap first if necessary, because they have to check for negative numbers and stuff anyway, it's faster than letting the loop do it, and the code is easier to reason about if `m>=k` is invariant in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I've added a bit more into the answer, but I'm not going to just steal your comment verbatim :)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the two inputs does not matter since for: `r = m%k`

```
if(m < k)
r = m
if(m == k)
r = 0
if(m > k)
r =  an integer number between 0 and k
```

And r is a number that keeps shrinking and shrinking until a number is found that can divide both numbers or 0 is reached.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the correct result because when you divide a smaller number by a greater number ,what you get as the modulus is the smaller number.

So, for example, **10%14** will give you **10**.
So ,in your logic ,if we take the example of 10 and 14 and pass **x** as **10**   and **y** as **14**, still we will get **2** as the answer which is correct.
Though in this code, the while loop will run one more time than if we pass **x** as **14** and **y** as **10**

Answer (score -1):

Actually It doesn't matter
Here's why

```
GCD(x,y)
  if (y == 0 ) return x
return GCD(y,x%y)
```

suppose x = 3, Y = 5

```
GCD(3,5) = GCD(5,3%5) = GCD(5,3) = GCD(3,2) .....
```